# WEBI BO Based on today display next day (dayname) if value match

Tags: date, calculation, webi

Hi So I have table with booking dates which is just 2 columns... 
country and bookings 
each country can be booked only on one day. Monday - Friday and that "day" is indicated in second column. 
Is there a calculation available to say based on today what the next slot is: (based on Day from table) but if today is Monday and slots are on Monday it will display date for next Monday etc....

so basically today (Wednesday) i need a calculation that will check what is the next booking available and show the date: 
so if next one is Thursday in file I need it to display 14/03/2019 
if in the file is Wednesday I would need it to display next week as today is to late so 20/03/2019

Answer (score 0):

in case anybody is looking for the same thing...
I've got it working... maybe not the most beautiful solution but works..

= If   [v Next Dry]="Monday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Monday" Then  RelativeDate(CurrentDate();7) 
ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Monday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Tuesday" Then RelativeDate(CurrentDate();6)
ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Monday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Wednesday" Then RelativeDate(CurrentDate();5)
ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Monday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Thursday" Then RelativeDate(CurrentDate();4) 
ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Monday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Friday" Then RelativeDate(CurrentDate();3)
ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Monday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Saturday" Then RelativeDate(CurrentDate();2) 
ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Monday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Sunday" Then RelativeDate(CurrentDate();1)

ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Tuesday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Monday" Then  RelativeDate(CurrentDate();1) 
ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Tuesday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Tuesday" Then RelativeDate(CurrentDate();7)
ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Tuesday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Wednesday" Then RelativeDate(CurrentDate();6)
ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Tuesday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Thursday" Then RelativeDate(CurrentDate();5) 
ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Tuesday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Friday" Then RelativeDate(CurrentDate();4)
ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Tuesday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Saturday" Then RelativeDate(CurrentDate();3) 
ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Tuesday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Sunday" Then RelativeDate(CurrentDate();2)

ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Wednesday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Monday" Then  RelativeDate(CurrentDate();2) 
ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Wednesday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Tuesday" Then RelativeDate(CurrentDate();1)
ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Wednesday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Wednesday" Then RelativeDate(CurrentDate();7)
ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Wednesday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Thursday" Then RelativeDate(CurrentDate();6) 
ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Wednesday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Friday" Then RelativeDate(CurrentDate();5)
ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Wednesday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Saturday" Then RelativeDate(CurrentDate();4) 
ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Wednesday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Sunday" Then RelativeDate(CurrentDate();3)

ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Thursday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Monday" Then  RelativeDate(CurrentDate();3) 
ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Thursday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Tuesday" Then RelativeDate(CurrentDate();2)
ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Thursday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Wednesday" Then RelativeDate(CurrentDate();1)
ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Thursday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Thursday" Then RelativeDate(CurrentDate();7) 
ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Thursday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Friday" Then RelativeDate(CurrentDate();6)
ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Thursday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Saturday" Then RelativeDate(CurrentDate();5) 
ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Thursday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Sunday" Then RelativeDate(CurrentDate();4)

ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Friday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Monday" Then  RelativeDate(CurrentDate();4) 
ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Friday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Tuesday" Then RelativeDate(CurrentDate();3)
ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Friday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Wednesday" Then RelativeDate(CurrentDate();2)
ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Friday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Thursday" Then RelativeDate(CurrentDate();1) 
ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Friday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Friday" Then RelativeDate(CurrentDate();7)
ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Friday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Saturday" Then RelativeDate(CurrentDate();6) 
ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Friday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Sunday" Then RelativeDate(CurrentDate();5)

ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Saturday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Monday" Then  RelativeDate(CurrentDate();5) 
ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Saturday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Tuesday" Then RelativeDate(CurrentDate();4)
ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Saturday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Wednesday" Then RelativeDate(CurrentDate();3)
ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Saturday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Thursday" Then RelativeDate(CurrentDate();2) 
ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Saturday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Friday" Then RelativeDate(CurrentDate();1)
ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Saturday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Saturday" Then RelativeDate(CurrentDate();7) 
ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Saturday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Sunday" Then RelativeDate(CurrentDate();6)

ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Sunday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Monday" Then  RelativeDate(CurrentDate();6) 
ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Sunday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Tuesday" Then RelativeDate(CurrentDate();5)
ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Sunday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Wednesday" Then RelativeDate(CurrentDate();4)
ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Sunday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Thursday" Then RelativeDate(CurrentDate();3) 
ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Sunday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Friday" Then RelativeDate(CurrentDate();2)
ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Sunday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Saturday" Then RelativeDate(CurrentDate();1) 
ElseIf [v Next Dry]="Sunday" And DayName(CurrentDate()) ="Sunday" Then RelativeDate(CurrentDate();7)